# Grails where queries from static context?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

according to the Grails (2.1.1) documentation i should be able to
create pre-defined where queries like below:

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static simpsons = where {
         lastName == "Simpson"
    }
    …
}
```

And use it like:

```
Person.simpsons.each {
    println it.firstName
}
```

However whatever i try, Grails/Java keeps telling me that i cannot
access non static content from a static reference which i understand
:) But how can i achieve something such as described in the docs? I normally use namedQueries, but i really like the easy of use of defining a where query.

Answer (score 0):

Looking the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/where.html) and [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#whereQueries) they don't say nothing special about static where clauses, you are trying to access the non static *firstName* property from a static content, that is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

You may be really interested in the [namedQueries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) , that is probably what you are looking for.

```
static namedQueries = {
       simpsons {
           eq(lastName,"Simpson")
       }
}
```

And then:

```
Person.simpsons.list().each {
    println it.firstName
}
```